# How is the idea of "X comes a distant third" commonly expressed in French?

Tags: expressions, anglais, allemand

We were having a conversation in German. Citing, one by one, three reasons why I think my friend has been hired for a job, I said jokingly:

> Die Antwort ist denkbar einfach. Erstens X. Zweitens Y. Dein Liebreiz **rangiert abgeschlagen auf Platz Drei**.

Or, as is more commonly phrased:

> Dein Liebreiz (**weit**) **abgeschlagen auf dem dritten Platz liegt**/**landet**.

In English, this is where we say:

> First, X. Second, Y. And your charm **comes a distant third** {/ comes in a distant third place}. The answer is as simple as that!

---

Basically, I need to deftly add the idea of "distant" to something like:

> Ton charme ne serait qu'au troisième rang sur leur liste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plutôt que « rang » en français j'utiliserais « place » ou « position » (mon choix préféré).

On ne traduirait pas forcément *distant* qui fait partie de l'expression idiomatique en anglais (*a distant* + *ordinal number*). Mais quand on veut insister sur l'écart entre les éléments on ajoute en général « loin derrière ». Et on peut aussi ajouter « très  » si on veut insister plus.

> Ton charme ne viendrait que (très) loin derrière en troisième position.

Ou au contraire si on veut moduler en sens inverse on peut mettre « assez » :

> Ton charme ne viendrait qu'assez loin derrière en troisième position.

Comment: @Laure: dans ce genre de contexte je verrais mieux « ne vient qu'en bon troisième ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui dans ce contexte précis, ça marche cependant personnellement je ne le généraliserais pas dans tous les cas pour *a distant  X*